# access models and forms within modules

Tags: zend-framework

What is the best way to access my models and forms from a controller of a module?

Let's explain with "pictures":

```
/application/module/storage/controllers/IndexController.php
```

needs to call readAction in the class called storage_Model_Files in

```
/application/module/storage/models/Files.php
```

I've made this app's dir structure and these forms and models with zf.sh (Zend_Tool).

I've read about all sorts of ways of manually including these files. I want to lazy load them **much like everything is done automatically with the default module.** I can't seem to find how in the docs.

Does that make sense?

I have:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

in my application.ini file. So I can access my controllers fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the module explicitly. Your options are:

1.) add this to your application.ini

```
resources.modules.storage = ""
```

and create a file /application/module/storage/Bootstrap.php

```
class Storage_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
}
```

2.) Create a method in your Boostrap.php

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Storage_',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/storage',
    ));

    return $autoloader;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So, I only need to do this once per module? Will this also autoload forms?

What does the application.ini entry: resources.modules.storage = "" do?

Comment: Take a look at the link Vladimir provided. There is a section there about the Module Resource Autoloader. "When using module bootstraps with Zend_Application, an instance of Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader  will be created by default for each discrete module, allowing you to autoload module resources."

Comment: BTW; you have to use either option 1 or 2. There is no need for both.

Comment: Perfect! OK, so, the two things I was doing was:
1. class case - my module dir is all lower case so Storage_Bootstrap doesn't work but storage_Bootstrap does.
2. I had done this before but, my module bootstrap class was extending Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap not Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap. 

That documentation link says it should just work - so I expect it to. It doesn't tell you what you need to glue it together. So thanks to Goran, it's all clear now and the glue is place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use autoloading:
http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html

Comment: "Resource autoloaders are intended to manage namespaced library code that follow Zend Framework coding standard guidelines, but which do not have a 1:1 mapping between the class name and the directory structure."

However, I do have a 1:1 class mapping between the class name and the directory structure.

I will amend my question to make this clearer.